# Regex with Dirname

Tags: php, regex, template-engine

Sorry for my bad english, but I want to ask a question.

I write an Templete engine for me.
Now i want make that i can write `@include(public/server/logik01/logik_web_init.php)` and the Class Includes that file and delete the `@include(....)` tag.

Here my code

```
private static function get_include(){
    preg_match_all('/@include.*/', self::$viewMainContent, $include);
    foreach($include[0] as $include){
        $key = explode("(", $include);
        $key = explode(")", $key[1]);
        $include = addcslashes($include, "/");
        $include =  '/'.$include.'/';
        self::$viewMainContent = preg_replace($include, '', self::$viewMainContent);
        require_once($key[0]);
    }
}
```

in the `self::$viewMainContent` are this `self::$viewMainContent = file_get_contents($viewMain);` sourcecode.

The INclude are good, but the `@include(public/server/logik01/logik_web_init.php)` i can't override with preg_replace

Comment: personally id match on this `@include\((?P<include>[^)]+)\)`, but that is just me, https://regex101.com/r/iC9kJ9/1  save you about 6 lines of code.

Comment: Thx for fast answer.
On which place i must write this `@include\((?P<include>[^)]+)\)`

Comment: to answer you question you may want to add `preg_quote($include)` to the preg replace to escape those nasty slashes and dots.

Comment: the original preg_match_all, then you just match and capture what you need, the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
 preg_match_all('/@include.*/', self::$viewMainContent, $include);
```

Try this

```
preg_match_all('/@include\((?P<include>[^)]+)\)/', '@include(public/server/logik01/logik_web_init.php)', $include);
```

result

```
include [9-49]  => `public/server/logik01/logik_web_init.php`
```

Then you can skip all the mess and just do something like this

To be clear you can just do something like this

```
 $include = array();
 preg_match_all('/@include\((?P<include>[^)]+)\)/', self::$viewMainContent, $include);
    $matches = isset($include['include']) ? count($include['include']) : 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < $matches; $i++) {
        require_once($include['include'][$i]);
    }
```

in any case the include wont work because you dont want to replace the content with the match of the regx but with the content of the included file.

for that you need to do this

```
ob_start();

 require_once($include['include'][$i]);

$content = ob_get_clean();
```

And then use the full match  `$inclue[0]` and replace it with the included content, in the original template..

Something like this

```
 $include = array();
 preg_match_all('/@include\((?P<include>[^)]+)\)/', self::$viewMainContent, $include);
$matches = count($include);
for($i = 0; $i < $matches; $i++) {
    ob_start();
    require_once($include['include'][$i]);
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    self::$viewMainContent = preg_replace('/'.preg_quote($include[0][$i]).'/', $content, self::$viewMainContent);
}
```

Of course I would use `file_get_contents` instead of include and then do all this before processing the template for any other tags, that would exclude using php inside of included template files and you wouldn't need output buffering `ob_*` functions..

Like so..

```
 $include = array();
 preg_match_all('/@include\((?P<include>[^)]+)\)/', self::$viewMainContent, $include);
$matches = count($include);
for($i = 0; $i < $matches; $i++) {
    $content = file_get_contents($include['include'][$i]);
    self::$viewMainContent = preg_replace('/'.preg_quote($include[0][$i]).'/', $content, self::$viewMainContent);
}
```

I haven't test this so sorry if it's not 100% correct but should get you down the right road.

Comment: I have testet with your last code and the include works but the `@include(/home/vagrant/Cloud/LogikServer/lizenzierung/public/server/logik01/logik_web_init.php)` ist not away from the browser.

Comment: This is not an easy thing you are trying to do...  I've written a few template engines,

Comment: ah sorry, the file that i would include are an php file with functions.
For the html files i have an other class.
like on my post

Comment: Well then you need output buffering if you want to capture the output. Otherwise just use the require for it.

Comment: Thank you for Help.
It does not work yet, but i work on it :-)

Comment: Good luck this might interest you .. https://github.com/ArtisiticPhoenix/Jet_Old although it's not fully complete yet

Answer (score 0):

Thx

The Template code are like this one.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{WEBROOT}/css/bundle.css">
</head>
<body>
  @include({SRVROOT}/public/server/logik01/logik_web_init.php)
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
      <div><img src="{WEBROOT}/img/mechtronik_2012.png"></div>
      <div>E-Shop Stromschienen</div>
      <div><a href="#" id="btnLogout"><img src="{WEBROOT}/img/grey_log-out1.png"><span>Logout</span></a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <div class="flex">
        <div class="border-panel">
          <legend>Login</legend>
          <button id="startLogik" class="button" name="start">Konfigurator starten</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{WEBROOT}/js/logikscripte.js"></script>
</body>
```

And i want i can more tha one `@include`

It works now with this code

```
$include = array();
    preg_match_all('/@include\((?P<include>[^)]+)\)/', self::$viewMainContent, $include);
$matches = isset($include['include']) ? count($include['include']) : 0;
for($i = 0; $i < $matches; $i++) {
        require_once($include['include'][$i]);
        self::$viewMainContent = preg_replace('/'.preg_quote($include[0][$i], '/').'/', '', self::$viewMainContent);
}
```

Comment: `'/'.preg_quote($include).'/'` notice the leading `/` and trailing.